# how to compile and run this program, pthread issue?

Tags: c++

I would like to compile the following program that makes alignment of fasta sequences, the program is available in:

http://compbio.cs.princeton.edu/mems/

I have downloaded a zip file called sparseMEM and downloaded the g++ in Ubuntu Linux, in the directory created there is a Makefile archive, so I tried to compile with make. The problem is that I got the following error:

```
g++ -lpthread -O3 -DSIXTYFOURBITS mummer.o qsufsort.o sparseSA.o fasta.o -o mummer
mummer.o: In function `main':
mummer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x480): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
mummer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4a8): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
sparseSA.o: In function `sparseSA::MEM(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::vector<match_t, std::allocator<match_t> >&, int, bool, int)':
sparseSA.cpp:(.text+0x3bbc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
sparseSA.cpp:(.text+0x3be0): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mummer] Error 1
```

how I can make it run?

also if somebody knows how to test this program it would be great

thanks

Comment: Remove `-lpthread`. Add `-pthread`.

Comment: Libraries specified with the -l option always should appear after .o files, order matters here.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you need `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.